# regular and between nested array mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document like this in mongodb

```
 {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "56b7451fa91b80e2078b4567"
        },
        "number": "222",
        "value": "hello",
        "name": "James",
        "username": "mahsa",

        "lessons": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "time": "2016-02-11 07:15:00",
                "term": "3"
                "marks": [
                    {
                     "id": "4",
                      "value": "10",
                     },
                     {
                      "id": "5",
                      "value": "9",

                     }
                 ]
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "time": "2016-02-11 07:45:00",
                "term": "4"

            }
        ]
    }
```

I'd like to push a nested array only when my variables are exactly this: `array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'2','lessons.term'=>'3')` 
after

```
"id": "2", "time": "2016-02-11 07:15:00", "term": "3"
```

, but when I use

```
array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'2','lessons.term'=>'4')
```

or

```
 array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'3','lessons.term'=>'3')
```

has a similar result 
my code is

```
$this->collection->update(
array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'2','lessons.term'=>'3'),
array('$push'=>array(
'lessons.$.marks'=> array(
    array('id'=>'444','value'=>'100'),
    array('id'=>'555','value'=>'90')
))));
```

Can I solve this problem or mongo can't support somethings like this?

Comment: Try different approaches and then ask us if there is any problem which you are not able to solve.

Comment: Is it possible for you to read my comments after answer.I tried hard but I can't solve this problem.@dikesh

Answer (score 0):

Mongo does support it, you just need to use the proper syntax:

```
{
  'number': '222',
  'lessons': {
      '$elemMatch': {
          'id' : '3',
          'term': '3'
      }
  }
}, {
  '$push': {
    'lessons.$.marks': {
      '$each': [{
        'id': '444',
        'value': '100'
      }, {
        'id': '555',
        'value': '90'
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Here is probably what you need in PHP:

```
$this->collection->update(
 array('number'=>'222',
 array('$elemMatch'=>array('lessons.id'=>'2','lessons.term'=>'3')),
    array('$push'=>array(
    'lessons.$.marks'=> array(
        '$each'=>array(
        array('id'=>'444','value'=>'100'),
        array('id'=>'555','value'=>'90')
)))));
```

Comment: By this when my array as ceriria  is array('number'=>'222','lessons.id'=>'3','lessons.term'=>'3') mongo pushed array again!

Comment: I 'd like to push  marks array only only when both of elements of nested array are exactly like this:  lessons.id=2 and lessons.term=3 but when I tried with lessons.id=3 and lessons.term=3, mongo pushed my array again  @codyayers

Comment: That must be on the PHP side of things... The query works if you paste it directly into Robomongo or another tool.

Comment: @sahar21 that error may be what you should actually expect if the document does not exist. I'd bet if you change the query parameter to something that finds a document it will work and not throw an error. You may want to try a find first, then update in this particular scenario or program around the error in PHP.

Comment: I fix the exception in php but nothing happened. By $elemMatch can't find this document:(